# Break large KML into multiple (smaller) KMLs

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, maps, kml

How do you break down a large KML into multiple smaller KML files that are referenced by a parent KML file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to have multiple simultaneous KMLs referenced in one parent KML is using the [NetworkLink element](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklink).

Here is a a file that uses one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<NetworkLink>
  <name>Loads Point.kml</name>
  <Link>
    <href>http://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/Point.kml</href>
  </Link>
</NetworkLink>
</kml>
```